# MongoDB sample specific times from each group

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working around MongoDB trying to figure out how to select random elements from each group after grouping the table by specific column.

Here is example table I am working on, basically I want select 2 documents for each "item", like 2 documents where "item" is "abc", 2 documents where "item" is "xyz" and so on.

[image: table]

I looked at the "sample" aggregation function, but cannot find how to make it work with "group"

Looked for similar questions, but could not find any with a real answer, as I like to code this exclusively in the mongodb query

Thanks

Comment: You can do it like this in 3 aggregation stages: group by item and add document to array, project the first two elements of array, and finally unwind the array. See [Aggregation pipeline stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for description for each stage.

Comment: Got it, thanks for response, but I dont want the first 2 elements, I want random 2 elements. I want elements to be randomly choosen each time I execute the query.

Comment: For that you can do something like this: for each item get a count, then get 2 random numbers within that count, get the 2 documents from the array, using using the 2 random numbers as index. This will be JavaScript function using the output from the previous _comment_  (without the third stage).

Answer (score 2):

The aggregation query samples of 2 documents for each "item" (1, if there is only one document for the item).

The sampled documents are picked randomly, based on two unique random numbers generated for each "item", within the query. For each run the sampled documents will be different.

*The Query:*

```
db.items.aggregate( [
 { $group: { _id: "$item", items: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
 { $addFields: { 
       origItems: "$items",
       rand1: { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: "$count" } ] } },
       indexes: {
              $map: {
                   input: "$items",
                   as: "it",
                   in: { "ix": { $indexOfArray: [ "$items", "$$it" ] } }
               }
        }
 } },
 { $addFields: { 
        indexes: { 
               $filter: { 
                    input: "$indexes",
                    as: "it",
                    cond: { $ne: [ "$$it.ix", "$rand1"  ] }
               }
         }
 } },
 { $addFields: { 
       rand: { 
          $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: { $subtract: [ "$count", 1 ] } } ] } 
         } 
 } },
 { $project: { rand2: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$indexes.ix", "$rand" ] }, 
               rand1: 1, origItems: 1, count: 1, indexes: 1 } 
 },
 { $project: { 
     filteredItems: { 
        $filter: {
           input: "$origItems",
           as: "it",
           cond: { 
               $or: [ { $eq: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$origItems", "$$it" ] }, "$rand1" ] }, 
                      { $eq: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$origItems", "$$it" ] }, "$rand2" ] } ]
            }
        } 
     }
 } },
 { $unwind: "$filteredItems" },
 { $project: { item: "$_id", _id: "$filteredItems._id" } }
] )
```

Example documents used for testing:

```
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 10 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 2 }
{ "item" : "c", "qty" : 12 }
{ "item" : "b", "qty" : 44 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 67 }
{ "item" : "b", "qty" : 31 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 9 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 51 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 550 }
{ "item" : "a", "qty" : 781 }
{ "item" : "b", "qty" : 9900 }
```

Comment: Hi @prasad_ Getting an error here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/h8pWtZuG4_e
Can you tell how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: found this fix `{ $rand: {}},` substitute for prior `_rand(),` https://mongoplayground.net/p/XSlzxzovHEJ from I believe your other solution https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/sample-x-number-of-documents-in-each-group-with-or-after-a-group-stage/170787/2
https://pastebin.com/shYz88kq
thanks again. Be well!

Comment: Better playground Formatted Output:
https://www.humongous.io/app/playground/mongodb/63654d15c77f2b531a3b4bce

Answer (score 1):

This procedure is to generate a sample of items, with 2 documents per item (or 1, if there is 1 only), from the `items` collection. Note the two documents for each item are randomly picked.

The code is run from *mongo shell*, uses aggregate query and JavaScript functions.

```
// Function returns two unique random indexes for a given array size.
// If the array size is 1, the second index will be -1.
function get2Randoms(n) {
    if (n == 1) { 
        return { n1: 0, n2: -1 } 
    };
    let r1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(n));
    let r2 = r1;
    while(r1 == r2) {
        r2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(n));
    }
    return { n1: r1, n2: r2 };
}

// Stores all the sample items; the result.
var random_items = [ ];

// Adds random document(s) for each item to random_items array.
function getRandomItems(doc) {
    let rs = get2Randoms( doc.count );
    random_items.push( doc.items[rs.n1] );
    if (rs.n2 >= 0) {
        random_items.push( doc.items[rs.n2] );
    }
}

// This query populates the random_items array.
db.items.aggregate( [
    { $group: { _id: "$item", items: { $push: "$$ROOT" }, count: { $sum: 1 } } },
]
).forEach( doc => getRandomItems(doc) )
```

The **result** (using sample documents, below) will have 7 items (2 each for items "a", "b" *and* 1 each for "c", "d", "e").

**Sample Documents:**

```
{ item: "a", qty: 10 },
{ item: "b", qty: 2 },
{ item: "c", qty: 12 },
{ item: "b", qty: 44 },
{ item: "a", qty: 67 },
{ item: "b", qty: 31 },
{ item: "d", qty: 9 },
{ item: "a", qty: 51 },
{ item: "a", qty: 550 },
{ item: "e", qty: 2 }
```